# Clustering documents on time

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, temporal

I have a number of documents created at various times. I want to **temporally cluster** these documents.

*i.e.* I want to cluster the documents into groups of documents with related timestamps. For example, if there is a "spike" in number of documents created at time X, they will be grouped into the same cluster and so on...

Assume we do not know how many clusters there may be.

Comment: Google "burst detection", "spike detection", "peak detection". The fact that you're looking at documents is largely irrelevant, just see them as point events.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know how many clusters have, growing newral gas is good algorithm to start.
You can play with demos here: http://www.demogng.de/

In your task you need 1D case.

You can find one of implementations here: https://github.com/BelBES/libGNG